# React build not execute scripts in index.htm

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nginx

I'm trying to deploy my reactJs app in to nginx server.when i run `serve -s build`,app successfully deployed but not execute scripts.

**index.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link async rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <link async rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" /> 
  <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            console.log("Will the service worker register?");
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js')
              .then(function(reg){
                console.log("Yes, it did.");
              }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log("No it didn't. This happened: ", err)
              });
          }    

  </script> 

  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

localhost it's working charmly.serviceworker script run and displayed message in browser console.also application tab showed serviceworker status.but not in server.

Comment: console.log is removed in the production build if you use CRA + service worker

Comment: @RajendranNadar but it's also not show service-worker status in Application tab